# Need explanation for this code block java

Tags: java, string, collections

Recently had a chance to get to know the recruitment process of java freshers.
sadly no one made it to second round because of this program. So as a enthusiast i asked one of my friend to give me solution so it, but as i am new to java and still not exposed to collection framework i didn't understood much of it.
So can explain this logic or code.

question was remove duplicate from string without using String class methods.?!

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str="this is java this is cpp";

        List<String> l=new LinkedList<String>();
        int i=0,j;
        for(i=0,j=str.indexOf(' ');j!=-1;i=j,j=str.indexOf(' ', i+1))
        {
            String s=str.substring(i,j).trim();
            l.add(s);
        }
        String s=str.substring(i+1,str.length()).trim();
        l.add(s);

        Iterator<String> it=l.iterator();
        List<String> list=new LinkedList<String>();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String s1=it.next();
            if(!list.contains(s1)){
                list.add(s1);
            }else
            {
                list.remove(s1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

in for loop i is checking the index of String but what j is all about ?
for now i know that only `(i=0;i<string.length();i++ )` kind of for loop... didn't get the extra int within for loop.

by the way how complex is this program for java freshers..just passed out ?

Comment: It's a pretty standard (if contrived) string processing function...should not be too hard to write if you are familiar with string processing. (Try writing, for example, a string-reversing function by yourself as an exercise).

Comment: yes sir i am practicing programming skills , taking coderbyte , codingbat programs :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .. its not my code.. i am new to java.. i didnt wrote it

Comment: This code is pretty ugly IMO...

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the logic inside the final `while` loop.  The `if` statement is correct, but if you encounter a duplicate you should not be removing the one already in your list.

```
 Iterator<String> it = l.iterator();
 List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
     String s1 = it.next();
     if (!list.contains(s1)) {
         list.add(s1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

in a `for` loop, you can use 3 parts each for a specific matter:

```
for ( /* part1 */ ; /* part2 */ ; /* part3 */ )
```

first of all, all these 3 parts are compulsory and if you write `for(;;)` you would probably need an infinite loop, though you need to `break` anyhow!

in part1, you can initiate any number of variables separating with a `,`

```
for(int i=0, int j=-10, int k=0 ; ... ; ...)
```

in part2 you can check any number of conditions to make the loop finished

```
for( .... ; i<=j, j>10, i<500 ; ...)
```

and finally, in part3 you have the right to perform some operations (usually increasing counters) for any number of variables

```
for(.... ; ... ; i++, j++, k+=2)
```

with all these in mind, your code is trying to split sub-strings and show a distinct collection of words from the main string `str`.

**HOW?**

```
j = str.indexOf(' ', i+1)
```

does the trick. it'll find the next blank `' '` part of your main string and tries to pull a sub-string from current index up to next blank space. need more explanation?